# Finding <?> symbols in textview

Tags: android, textview, symbols

I tried a lot of things even tried changing the font of textview but could not get the expected result.
Actually, I am just reading a `.txt` file from my raw folder and then displaying it in the textview.
But I am facing a problem when characters like hyphen `-` and apostrophe `'` appear. Not everywhere but the textview replaces those characters with `?` symbol.

Attaching a screenshot of both, the file in notepad as well as textview.

[image: Check this image]

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: the encoding is ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution to the problem
Just converted the file encoding format from **ANSI to UTF-8**.
other formats like big endian and unicode do not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your string in an array then compare "?" ASCII code with array cells.
get your ASCII number in this link :

> http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to read the file as UTF-8 otherwise your file might be interrupted (open as ASCII and saved;) :

```
InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```